# How to pass a Rust function to onclick inside html button tag?

Tags: rust, rocket

I want to pass a rust function for the onClick in my button tag. I know how to pass a variable but a function not.

Below is my rust file where I call the routes:

```
use rocket_dyn_templates::{context, Template};
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Context {
    prompt: String,
}

#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;

fn submit(prompt: String) {
    println!("value is {prompt}");
}

#[get("/")]
fn index() -> Template {
    let prompt: String = "".to_string();
    Template::render("index", context! { field: prompt })
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build()
        .mount("/", routes![index])
        .attach(Template::fairing())
}
```

My html file:

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    <title>Generator Image</title>body {
      background: #1a6875;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .container-prompt {
      height: 10em;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .submit-prompt {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-submit">
    <div class="submit-prompt">
      <input method="text" name="prompt" id="prompt"/>
      <button onClick="">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

At the end, I would like to use the variable prompt used in the input tag on the rust function as a parameter when the button is clicked.

Thanks.